# How to address the files that their absolute path is unknown?

Tags: java, file, file-io, path

I'm developing a java desktop application. the folders which are going to be installed on the end user computer are: Sources, Images and... . the Sources folder is the folder where the program sources exist(Classes) and the Images folder is the place where the images which the program needs them exist. 
now in the program, how should I address my images?

I mean I don't know absolute path of my image files(as I don't know where the user decides to install the program), just know they will be in Images Folder...

Comment: Obviously you should use relative paths. Like `../Images`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the images folder can be determined relative to the running program, or the user will have to tell you where the images are stored. The user may want images from a number of directories in which case you will have to either scan for them or ask the user where they are. e.g. The Add Library function is music programs.

Comment: could you explain more that which folders are determined `relative` to each other?

Comment: For example, if you know that the Images directory will always be in the same directory, or the same parent as the JARs, you can use a relative path to find them.  Generally it's not a good idea to have working files with the executable but have them as a sub-directory of the user's home directory.

Comment: Think about `Program Files` and `Users\user\My Images` in windows or `/usr/local` and `/home/user/Images` under unix.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the best solution to solve this problem but if i have problem like yours i'll do next steps:

1. You can use environment variables where user (or you) can add your application path (or another path you want).
2. Or like [madhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502452/java-how-to-address-the-files-that-their-absolute-path-is-unknown/14502545#comment20213463_14502452) advice "use relative path"
3. Or you can ask user to choose directory for this purpose, and save information about it to configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

If your program will start from the directory containing the Sources and Images folders then you can refer them by Images/imageFile.